# How to set TLS cipher suites for gRPC server and client programmatically in C++?

Tags: c++, ssl, encryption, grpc

How to set SSL/TLS cipher suites for a `grpc::Server` (e.g. using `grpc::ServerBuilder`) and a client `grpc::Channel` (e.g. constructed by `grpc::CreateChannel`) in C++?

I know there is the `GRPC_SSL_CIPHER_SUITES` environment variable, but is there a way to programmatically set the cipher suites without modifying the environment (i.e. without using `setenv()` or similar)?

Comment: Found any answer?

Comment: @abhiarora Nope.